# How do I lock read to tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, locking

I want when a session is running, other session don't read the table.
Can I do that?

first script is:

```
mysqli_query($con,"LOCK TABLES a READ");
for($i=0; $i<999999;$i++)
echo $i."\n";

mysqli_query($con,"UNLOCK TABLES");
```

and second script is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM a");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I ask because there are probably other ways to solve the problem you have, such as Transactions.

Comment: @DampeS8N I have a sequence of number (1,2,3,4,5) each two number (1,2) as group processed in one session. I want two prevent from twice processing of a group. `Excuse my bad English!!`

Comment: To do this add a 'processed' field to the table and populate it with 0s. When you get to each item, check if it is processed yet, if it isn't set it as processed = 1 and process it.

Comment: @DampeS8N My web server is very unstable and every time server down!

Comment: Then you should consider Transactions. You'll be able to open the transaction, do everything, then commit the transaction and if it stops part way, none of the changes will take place.

Comment: @DampeS8N You say `begin_transaction; set processed = 1; do somthing; commit;`? then if two session of group (1,2) run, what happened?